# Does logistic regression use crosstabs?

Tags: contingency-tables, logit

I am performing a binomial logistic regression with my outcome being a count with an upper bound which is 45.  My data is of the following form:

[image]

Now I am wondering whether the actual analysis happens on a crosstab or not? I am confused since I have 45 categories and also continuous variables so that would make to many cells, increasing the chance of empty cells? I want to know, because I want to know how many degrees of freedom I have, and whether this depends on my sample size, or the cells of a crosstab.

Comment: Logistic regression does not apply to count outcomes; it only applies to *binary* outcomes. What are you *really* doing?

Comment: @whuber You are right. My outcome are proportions of successes to be exact. This is not binary, but it is a 0 to 1 interval. Is there another term for this type of regression?

Comment: You might want to regress on the *counts* themselves using Poisson regression.

Comment: I got the advice not to do this since there is an upper bound to the counts, and since some values are very close to this limit?

Comment: What is the reason for the upper bound?

Comment: There are 45 Bernouilli 'trials' in which there is success or not. In my case the respondents all receive exactly 45 questions, and the count is the number of nonresponses.

Comment: OK, it's not a bad idea to re-express the number of nonresponses $x$ with a logit, such as $y = \log((x+1/2)/46)$, for instance. Please note that this is not "binary"--there 46 distinct possible outcomes--nor is it what is called "logistic regression." The analysis would proceed exactly as any regression does, using $y$ as the dependent variable.

Comment: @whuber I'm not sure I follow you. What is the problem with regressing on logit(x/45) ? And is it not logistic regression because we use the log link function?

Comment: (1) The problem with logit(x/45) is that it is undefined when either x=0 or x=45. (2) Logistic regression *by definition* uses only 0-1 responses. It is based on a likelihood for outcomes of independent *Bernoulli* variates. Although the mathematical calculations to optimize the "likelihood" function will go through when other numerical values are offered as input, they make no sense.

Comment: I think in a way the likelihood uses 0-1 responses, however, it accounts for the fact that these came from more than 1 trial. Not sure if we are talking about the same thing, but this wikilink describes my model: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#In_terms_of_binomial_data

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. However, that doesn't look like an appropriate model, because the 45 questions asked of each individual will *not* be independent and in fact would not even be expected to represent the same kind of outcome. What *would* be valid would be to have one record for each question for each individual, coded with a binary dummy to indicate nonresponse or not. Apply logistic regression to those data, including the individuals and the questions as (categorical) explanatory variables. If the questions are *all* non-significant, your initial approach might be justified.

Comment: Thanks, I did account for the non-independence by allowing an extra parameter so that it is in fact beta-binomial. I considered your approach, but due to the model already being quite complex (3 levels and 50 000 individuals) I'd rather leave it at that.

Comment: Nowadays that is neither a large nor a complex problem. In fact, a model with just three levels always has been an extraordinarily small and simple problem. Using only one parameter for non-independence doesn't seem like it would work; I don't even see how it correctly handles the kind of dependence that should occur here.

Comment: Does it make a difference that the questions are on the same topic? Does that make the trials more 'similar' and the independence more of the kind handled by the overdispersion parameter?

Comment: That assumption--which still ought to be checked--would put you into a "repeated measures" situation and might be handled with a mixed GLM.  However, that assumption would normally be doubtful: missingness in questions arises from various question-specific causes, such as wording and position (questions late in a survey might just get skipped).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Doesn't my approach work when I want to research a general tendency to nonrespond. For example see which type of people have higher counts, despite the fact everyone received the same set of questions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9000/discussion-between-whuber-and-kwanti)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, logistic regression does not "happen on a cross tab". It happens on the data. The independent variables can be continuous, in which case a crosstab makes no sense.

And the output from any logistic regression should tell you how many df you have used. If the program you are using doesn't tell you that is not worth using